# SVG image outside panel is cropped

Tags: css, svg

I am trying to positioning a svg image on the border of a material expansion panel. The problem is that the svg image should be positioned a little outside of the panel.

But the svg image is cropped. I tried with z-index but there was no any effect.

Do you have any idea??

Wrong:

[image]

Expected:

[image]

css

```
.svg-class .mat-radio-container::after {

  display: block;
  content: url("../../assets/images/top-kondition3.svg");
  overflow: visible !important;
  margin: -31px;
}
```

html

```
      <mat-expansion-panel *ngFor="let element of elements" class="svg-class">
          <mat-expansion-panel-header matRipple>
            <mat-radio-button #radio (change)="onChanged($event)"></mat-radio-button>
           Hello
          </mat-expansion-panel-header>

        </mat-expansion-panel>          
    </mat-accordion>
```

Comment: in parent div there must be `overflow: hidden` you need to removed that

Comment: which parent div? mat-expansion-panel?

Comment: no, parent of mat-expansion-panel maybe you need to check that

Comment: `overflow: visible` are you meaning, If I set the property to `visible` I am getting the expected result.

Comment: yes, now you got your solution

Comment: I just write this as an answer if it works for you then you can marked this as accepted answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be `overflow: hidden` set in parent div maybe parent of `<mat-expansion-panel>`

so you need to assign `overflow:visible` to parent div then it will work